# error: response from deamon: failed to create task for container to create shim task

Tags: docker, armbian

I'm  trying to run docker run hello-world but i'm getting this error:

> error: response from deamon: failed to create task for container to
> create shim task> OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed:
> unable to start container process: error during container init: error
> setting cgroup config for porcHooks: bpf_prog_query(BPF_CGROUP_DEVICE)
> failed: invalid argument: unknow ERRO[0000] error wating for container

running

```
armbianmonitor -u
```

i got:

https://paste.armbian.com/eyobuholob

How do I fix this?